# How to calculate the total duration for two certain date-time in a CSV file (could occur multiple times) by using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I am working on one sample CSV file regarding the logs info from one vending machine. (pretty new to the pandas). Every day, there will be someone to reload the drinks to the machine by scanning the QR code on the bottle. I need to solve the below question:

Q: What's the total duration to reload all of the drinks to the machine?

You can find my sample code and sample CSV file below:

```py
import pandas as pd

filePath = '~/sample.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(filePath)

print(df.head(10))
```

[image]

Info regarding the type of each column
df.dtypes

- timestamp --> datetime64[ns]
- event     --> object
- value     --> object

Below are my thoughts to solve the problem:

1. there will be many event statuses, but I only need to focus on event == 'qc_scan':
   and value columns == 'Entered' or 'Exited'  (due there might be a value == 'error')

   so for each loading bottle duration is equal to:

   ```py
   qc_scan_starttime = df[event == 'qc_scan' & value == 'Entered'] #corrsonpidng timestamp

   qc_scan_endtime = df[event == 'qc_scan' & value == 'Exited'] #corrsonpidng timestamp

   each_duration = qc_scan_endtime - qc_scan_endtime
   ```
2. then loop through the whole data frame, and sum the each duration
3. save the duration as new column name as 'duration' (Units in mins)
4. eventually save as a new CSV file contains the duration info

But, I am not sure how to write a for loop within the CSV file and using python pandas. Can someone please provide me with a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

According to your question description, I don't think you need to create a new column. You can accomplish you goal by:

1. loop through the dataframe
2. find the duration between each `event == 'qc_scan' & value == 'Entered'` and `event == 'qc_scan' & value == 'Exited'`
3. sum the duration

---

There might exists some solution using special pandas functions, but I would recommend starting from the simplest way. That is:

1. you can use `iterrows` to iterate the df ([ref](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)). The syntax will look like this:

```py
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    event, value = row["event"], row["value"]
    if event == "qc_scan":
        # do something
```

2. And in the `# do something` part, you will need to store every duration seconds between an `Entered` and an `Exited`. That would be something like

```py
qc_scan_starttime = None
if value == "Entered":
    qc_scan_starttime = df["timestamp"]
elif value == "Exited":
    if qc_scan_starttime is not None:
        duration = df["timestamp"] - qc_scan_starttime
        total_duration += duration
        qc_scan_starttime = None
```

---

In the end, the whole solution would be

```py
total_duration = 0
qc_scan_starttime = None

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    event, value = row["event"], row["value"]
    if event == "qc_scan":
        if value == "Entered":
            qc_scan_starttime = df["timestamp"]
        elif value == "Exited":
            if qc_scan_starttime is not None:
                duration = df["timestamp"] - qc_scan_starttime
                total_duration += duration
                qc_scan_starttime = None
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Your solution is pretty straightforward and well explained. On the other hand, where should I save the "total duration"?  As you mentioned that no need to save into a new column. However, should I save it to a new table? Due to there might be multiples machines and multiple days. The ultimate goal is to analyze the qc_scan time in a visualized way to display the results. Thanks

Comment: @Lawrence, it seems like the scope of your question is bigger that it was posted. I suggest you to edit your question and provide all of the details (e.g. your ultimate goals? what did you plan to do with the df?) or create a new question for the remaining steps.

Comment: @Lawrence Another little suggestion: you can list all your steps down. Not only for you but also for others to be concrete with what you want to do and more importantly what is missed from your current plan.